# Espresso reporting "java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find test class." when run from a Library project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I have a multi-project app which consists of 3 library projects and 1 Application project.  One of the library projects contains all of my Activities and Views and it will be reused for similar apps in the future...so I would like to create and run all of my Espresso tests from there, so I can reuse the same tests on other Application projects which will use the same library.

It appears, that Espresso can only be run from the Application project.  When I create and run the Espresso tests from the App project, they are able to run no problem..

But when I create and run the Espresso tests from my Library project, where all of the Activities are anyway, it cannot find my Test Class...even though they are the same exact tests that ran successfully in the Application project.

Has anyone else had this problem.  I would add code samples but im working on a non-disclosure project.